# How to enable HyperLinq in Data Grid output

Tags: datagrid, linqpad

I have a LINQPad query that outputs HyperLinqs in one of the columns. I see that this works as expected in the Rich Text output format, but it doesn't seem to work in the Data Grid output. Clicking on the HyperLinq in the Data Grid output drills into the HyperLinq object, itself, rather than to the URL that has been specified. Am I missing something here, is this a bug, or is this simply not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. It will be fixed for the next beta build.

Comment: I'm looking forward to this fix.

Comment: The new beta is out: www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx